# Simple Injector Activation Exception Xamarin Forms. I can't navigate through my application

Tags: xamarin, simple-injector

I'm using simple injector for DI on my solution. After xamarin updating it stop working. I can navigate once and then it throws **Activation Exception : This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.**

Here is my App.xaml.cs

```cs
public App(Container container) {
    this.container = container;

    InitializeComponent();

    this.InitConfig();
}

private void InitConfig() {
    //Setup Styles to be used on different controls
    SetupResources();

    //Data Bindings
    DataBindings();

    //Service Bindings
    ServiceBindings();

    //Business Bindings
    BusinessBindings();

    //ViewModels Bindings
    ViewModelsBindings();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(
        container.GetInstance<ViewManager>()
        .Navigate<MainMenuViewModel>().View) {
        BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#7A7B7C")
    };

> this navigate works

    container.GetInstance<PendingRequestSender>().Start();
}
```

ViewModelsBinding:

```cs
protected void ViewModelsBindings() {
    container.Register<UIHelperService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    ViewManager viewManager = new ViewManager(container);
    container.RegisterSingleton(viewManager);
    viewManager.RegisterView<MainMenuView, MainMenuViewModel>();
    viewManager.RegisterView<AdjustInventoryView, AdjustInventoryViewModel>();
    viewManager.RegisterView<CustomerPickUpView, CustomerPickUpViewModel>();
    viewManager.RegisterView<CycleCountFullInventoryView, CycleCountFullInventoryViewModel>();
    viewManager.RegisterView<FinishReceiverView, FinishReceiverViewModel>();
    viewManager.RegisterView<FinishReceiverConfirmationView, FinishReceiverConfirmationViewModel>();
    viewManager.RegisterView<ProcessNotShipView, ProcessNotShipViewModel>();
}
```

ViewManager:

```cs
public class ViewManager {
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> modelToView;
    readonly Container container;

    public ViewManager(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
        modelToView = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    }

    public void RegisterView<V, M>() where V : Page where M : BaseViewModel {
        modelToView[typeof(M)] = typeof(V);
        container.Register<M>();
        container.Register<V>();
    }

    public ViewItem<Page, M> Navigate<M>() where M : BaseViewModel {
        M model = container.GetInstance<M>();
        Page view = (Page)container.GetInstance(modelToView[typeof(M)]);
        return new ViewItem<Page, M>(view, model);
    }
}
```

and for example I want to navigate in this way:

```cs
void OnReceiveShipmentClicked() {
    userManager.RunAuthenticated(() => {
        viewManager.Navigate<ReceiveShipmentViewModel>()
           .Setup((model) => {
               model.pallets = _localPalletService.RetrievePalletList(userManager.ID());
           })
           .Go();
    },
     TxtEnvironment);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression () [0x0003d] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression (SimpleInjector.InjectionConsumerInfo consumer) [0x00012] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression (SimpleInjector.InjectionConsumerInfo consumer) [0x00006] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameterFor (SimpleInjector.InjectionConsumerInfo consumer) [0x00016] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters (System.Type serviceType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor) [0x0001f] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression (System.Type serviceType, System.Type implementationType) [0x0002c] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation] () [0x00000] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyle+SingletonLifestyleRegistration`2[TService,TImplementation].BuildTransientExpression () [0x00000] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyle+SingletonLifestyleRegistrationBase`1[TService].CreateInstanceWithNullCheck () [0x00000] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) [0x00043] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:333 
at System.Lazy`1[T].ExecutionAndPublication (System.LazyHelper executionAndPublication, System.Boolean useDefaultConstructor) [0x00022] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:351 
at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00074] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:431 
at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:509 
at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyle+SingletonLifestyleRegistrationBase`1[TService].BuildExpression () [0x00000] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression (SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer producer) [0x00007] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal () [0x00011] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) [0x00043] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:333 
at System.Lazy`1[T].ExecutionAndPublication (System.LazyHelper executionAndPublication, System.Boolean useDefaultConstructor) [0x00022] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:351 
at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00074] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:431 
at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:509 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression () [0x0003e] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression (SimpleInjector.InjectionConsumerInfo consumer) [0x00012] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression (SimpleInjector.InjectionConsumerInfo consumer) [0x00006] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameterFor (SimpleInjector.InjectionConsumerInfo consumer) [0x00016] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters (System.Type serviceType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor) [0x0001f] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression (System.Type serviceType, System.Type implementationType) [0x0002c] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation] () [0x00000] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.TransientLifestyle+TransientLifestyleRegistration`2[TService,TImplementation].BuildExpression () [0x00000] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression (SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer producer) [0x00007] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal () [0x00011] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) [0x00043] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:333 
at System.Lazy`1[T].ExecutionAndPublication (System.LazyHelper executionAndPublication, System.Boolean useDefaultConstructor) [0x00022] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:351 
at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00074] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:431 
at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:509 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildInstanceCreator () [0x00000] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance () [0x00000] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance () [0x00052] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceFromProducer (SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer instanceProducer, System.Type serviceType) [0x0000a] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceForRootType[TService] () [0x0001d] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance[TService] () [0x0001f] in <215303bfc4464c2fb19e1665117477b4>:0 
at Warehouse.UI.Manager.ViewManager.Navigate[M] () [0x00001] in /Users/aragonzalez/Projects/Warehouse/Warehouse/UI/Manager/ViewManager.cs:25 
at Warehouse.UI.ViewModels.MainMenuViewModel.<OnReceiveShipmentClicked>b__48_0 () [0x00001] in /Users/aragonzalez/Projects/Warehouse/Warehouse/UI/ViewModels/MainMenuViewModel.cs:216 
at Warehouse.Business.UserManager+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Warehouse.Business.IUserManager.RunAuthenticated>b__2 () [0x00001] in /Users/aragonzalez/Projects/Warehouse/Warehouse/Business/UserManager.cs:32 
at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.14.1.39/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:152 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.14.1.39/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.14.1.39/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
at Warehouse.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/aragonzalez/Projects/Warehouse/iOS/Main.cs:15
```

I don't understand the exception and why it works the first time and then it throws the exception.

Comment: 1. Please always post the full stack trace. 2. Since you tagged this question with `simple-injector` you imply a relationship between the crash and the use of Simple Injector. Do you have any evidence that points into that direction?

Comment: @Steven I just added the full stack trace

Comment: The exception message "This instance has already started one or more requests." is *not* a message thrown by Simple Injector, which implies that the given stack trace and exception information is not complete. Please include the stack traces, exception types, and messages of all inner exceptions as well.